# Two variables with the same list have different IDs.....why is that?

Tags: python, list

Trying to understand the following

Why is it that the ID's assigned by Python are different for the same lists?

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 2, 3]

id(x) != id(y)
True

id(x)
11428848

id(y)
12943768
```

Comment: Because they are distinct lists. You create the same list twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every distinct *object* in Python has its own ID. It's not related to the contents -- it's related to the location where the information that describes the object is stored. Any distinct object stored in a distinct place will have a distinct id. (It's [*sometimes*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id), but not [*always*](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/ironpython-users/2005-March/000354.html), the memory address of the object.)

This is especially important to understand for mutable objects -- that is, objects that can be changed, like lists. If an object can be changed, then you can create two different objects with the same contents. They will have different IDs, and if you change one later, the second will not change.

For immutable objects like integers and strings, this is less important, because the contents can never change. Even if two immutable objects have different IDs, they are essentially identical if they have identical contents.

This set of ideas goes pretty deep. You can think of a variable name as a tag assigned to an ID number, which in turn uniquely identifies an object. Multiple variable names can be used to tag the same object. Observe:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> id(a)
4532949432
>>> id(b)
4533024888
```

That, you've already discovered. Now let's create a new variable name:

```
>>> c = b
>>> id(c)
4533024888
```

No new object has been created. The object tagged with `b` is now tagged with `c` as well. What happens when we change `a`?

```
>>> a[1] = 1000
>>> a
[1, 1000, 3]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
```

`a` and `b` are different, as we know because they have different IDs. So a change to one doesn't affect the other. But `b` and `c` are the same object -- remember? So...

```
>>> b[1] = 2000
>>> b
[1, 2000, 3]
>>> c
[1, 2000, 3]
```

Now, if I assign a new value to `b`, it doesn't change anything about the objects themselves -- just the way they're tagged:

```
>>> b = a
>>> a
[1, 1000, 3]
>>> b
[1, 1000, 3]
>>> c
[1, 2000, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks Senderle, real text book response, very good explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The why to that is that if you do that:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
m = [1, 2, 3]
l.append(4)
```

Ids should not be the same and ids must not change for any objects since they identify them.
All mutable objects works this way. But it is also the case for tuples (which are unmutable).

Edit: 
As commented below, the ids may refer to memory address in some python implementation but not in all.

Comment: This muddies the water a bit, but your first statement is not necessarily true in all implementations of python. It's true in  [cpython](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id); but I believe that (for example) IronPython works differently. It might be better to emphasize the invariants (from the above link): "This is an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime."

Comment: Edited to push that statement at the end of the answer with more information.

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't the same lists. They may contain identical information, but they are not the same. If you made y = x, you'd find that actually the id is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Python keep the mutable variables with different IDs, that's why.

You can check it with immutable object `id`s too; a tuple, for example.

Comment: Thanks qqvc - i see it now, just changed index 0 to 4 for x and did an ID check and it returned the same ID. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: `(1, 2, 3) is (1, 2, 3)` will also be `False` in an interpreter; it's not *just* about mutable vs. immutable.