# Python is operator

Tags: python

I understand that the "is" operator checks identity between two objects, but what is this?

```
a=25
b=25
a is b
True
```

Why is this true if

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
a is b
False
```

And from this post, https://www.quora.com/Python-is-operator, it says all immutable objects, like integers from the first example, will have the first example's result, True, but tuples are immutable and this happens:

```
a = (1,2)
b = (1,2)
a is b
False
```

Can someone explain please?

Thanks.

Comment: This is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189660/two-variables-in-python-have-same-id-but-not-lists-or-tuples

Comment: In summary, python does this for memory optimization (when it can).