# Why is the output different in both the cases?

Tags: python, list, tuples

Look at the following code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
# a is a reference to an object of type 'list'
b = [1, 2, 3]
# b is a reference to an object of type 'list'
print(a is b)
```

Output: `False`

```
a = (1, 2, 3)
# a is a reference to an object of type 'tuple'
b = (1, 2, 3)
# b is a reference to an object of type 'tuple'
print(a is b)
```

Output: `True`

Why is the output different in both cases? Has a *mutable* or an *immutable* structure got something to do with it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213129/discussion-on-question-by-niraj-raut-why-is-the-output-different-in-both-the-cas).

Answer (score 0):

if a and b are pointing to same address  then a is b gives true 
even thought they are not pointing to same address if values are same then a==b gives true

Comment: How does this address the OP's question? They're not asking what `is` does, they're asking why the behaviour is different between the two examples.

Answer (score 0):

'is' operator – Evaluates to true if the variables on either side of the operator point to the same object and false otherwise. if this explains!?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189660/two-variables-in-python-have-same-id-but-not-lists-or-tuples) should help

Comment: How does this address the OP's question? They're not asking what `is` does, they're asking why the behaviour is different between the two examples.

Comment: That is explained in the other thread already, please check the link.

Comment: Then this isn't really an answer, and the question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I don't have privilege to do that, so I pointed out the link and summary. Edit: Did It.

Comment: Then please wait [until you do](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), that doesn't excuse posting non-answers. See e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/248731.

Comment: If you go through tons of questions here a lot of them have been pointed to other links. I learned and did that way. But I did post summarized answer.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but at least now you know better than to keep making that mistake!

Answer (score 0):

`is` compares the IDs (which are the memory addresses in CPython), `==` compares equality.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
# a is a reference to an object of type 'list'
b = [1, 2, 3]
# b is a reference to an object of type 'list'
print(id(a), id(b))
print(hex(id(a)), hex(id(b)))
print(a is b)


a = (1, 2, 3)
# a is a reference to an object of type 'tuple'
b = (1, 2, 3)
# b is a reference to an object of type 'tuple'
print(hex(id(a)), hex(id(b)))
print(id(a), id(b))
print(a is b)
```

Comment: How does this address the OP's question? They're not asking what `is` does, they're asking why the behaviour is different between the two examples.

Comment: @jonrsharpe They want to know why one gives an output of true and the other false. Understanding what `is` does answers the why one gives true and the other false. The additional print statements show what `is` is comparing.

Comment: ...does it? It would be perfectly reasonable to have a Python implementation that works exactly as described here where `a is not b` in *both* cases. As I mentioned above, the question isn't about the implementation of `is`, but why tuples get reused.

Comment: His question "Why is the output different in both cases?" the answer is because the `id` values are different on one case and the same in the other case.

Comment: Sure, but... *why* are they the same IDs in the second case but not the first? They both look to be creating separate objects. That's what your answer fails to address, and what the OP is actually asking.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, the owner asked "Why is the output different in both cases?" Not "why are they the same IDs in the second case but not the first".  The answer to that question is that the python memory manager is pointing both variables to the same address in memory for the immutable object and different objects in memory for the mutable object.

Comment: ...what? I know that isn't what they asked, but *that's what your answer tells them* - that's my point! You don't actually explicitly say that the ID is the memory address, and this is *also* implementation-dependent. And you don't explain how and why a given implementation might reuse the underlying tuple object in the second case. This is a very surface-level answer, they're identical because they're the same object, but doesn't actually explain the reason.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok, I edited the answer to explicitly say: "'is' compares the IDs which are the memory addresses"

Comment: Again, that's a [CPython implementation detail](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id), and it still doesn't address the actual question - why do they have the same memory address, **why are they the same object?**

Answer (score -2):

[image: it is false and it is same for both lists and tupless]

```
if a=[1,2,3]
```

and b=a
then a is b gives true

if a=[1,2,3] and b=[1,2,3] then a is b gives true

it is same for both lists and tuples

Comment: when we are writing a=b it is pointing to same address so a is b gives true

Comment: It is same both for lists and tuples .The question is wrong .

Comment: You have got a different output because you are working on a different implementation. It's completely implementation-defined. My question is correct.

Comment: It isn't *wrong*, it's *implementation dependent*. For example, I see the tuples being identical if I put this in a `.py` file and run it, but *not* if I do the same example in the REPL, even for the same version of CPython 3.