# Interning objects in shell and .py file

Tags: python, memory-management

In Python shell if we do:

```bash
>>> a = 98765
>>> b = 98765
>>> a is b
>>> False
```

However, when we run the following .py file:

```py
a = 98765
b = 98765
print(a is b)
```

Output

```bash
True
```

This is understandable because Python seems to be optimising memory by interning immutable objects.

Why is this treated differently in a Python shell?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38189759/10065556) states

> Generally speaking, every time you define an object in Python, you'll create a new object with a new identity

which seems to be wrong when we are defining immutable objects in a .py file.

Comment: are you asking why doesnt it intern when in the shell? or why does it intern when running in a script ? ... in anycase the shell is a subtly different environment in a few ways (ie `_` for last result), in addition interning of immutable objects is also an implementation detail that you shouldnt rely upon being always the case ...

Comment: I wanted to understand the reason why it doesn't intern when in the shell -- when memory wise it's efficient to do so. Is it "hard" to do that? If yes, why?